# Specific package version not available

Tags: linux, debian

I am using Debian(buster)I would like to download a specific version of a package. To accomplish this I added the required repository to the system and ran the apt-get update command. Also I use 'apt-cache-madison "package-name" to verify that the package i need it available and it does show up. So when i run the command to install the package "apt-get install 'package'='version_number' " it says that the Version 'the version i specified' was not found for 'package'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the package for the availability before :

```
apt policy <package>
apt-cache madison <package>
apt list -a <package>
```

If the desired version isn't available, that's mean the package cannot be installed.

Here is an example:

```
~$ apt policy linux-image-amd64

linux-image-amd64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.19+105+deb10u8
  Version table:
     5.9.6-1~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.19+105+deb10u8 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     4.19+105+deb10u7 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

From the output 3 version are allowed to be installed `4.19+105+deb10u7`, `4.19+105+deb10u8` and `5.9.6-1~bpo10+1`. To simulate the installation:

```
sudo apt install -s linux-image-amd64=4.19+105+deb10u7
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used the apt policy <package> as you suggested and the version that I want to download does show up. I tried to install the package while specifying the repo with the -t command but it still tells me the package is not found.

Comment: @manhasnoname could you add the package name, please.

Comment: I figured it out. It was an error in my sources file. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

You can target the package version with the repository name.

Assuming your package is in Testing, you can use

```
apt-get install <package>/testing
```

or

```
apt-get install <package> -t testing
```

The first command only installs the corresponding package, the second one installs both package and dependencies from testing

Be sure to read about "[FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)" (these advises apply for every Linux distribution) before installing packages from another repo

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using the -t flag as you suggested but I'm still getting the same error. Just to confirm the name of the repo is what you specify in the /sources.list file ? You can name your repo whatever you would like?

Comment: I don't know for the naming. Here is an abstract of my file `/etc/apt/sources.list` :
`deb http://ftp.belnet.be/debian testing main contrib`